# How to assign multiple css classes as an array to a jsx variable in React, and then assign the variable to the className with join() function

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './SideDrawer.css';
import Logo from '../../Logo/Logo';
import NavigationItems from '../NavigationItems/NavigationItems';
import Backdrop from '../../UI/Backdrop/Backdrop';
import Aux from '../../../hoc/Auxiliary';

const sideDrawer = (props) => {
```

Since I am not able to assign className in the format of
`class.SideDrawer`, I have to use the format in `className='SideDrawer'`

```
let attachedClasses= {
    <div className = 'SideDrawer' 'Closed'></div>
}


if(props.open){
return(
        attachedClasses=<div className= 'SideDrawer' 'Open'> </div> 
    )
}


return(
    <Aux>
        <Backdrop show={props.open} clicked={props.closed}/>
```

Also I cannot assign the variable `attachedClasses` to `className`
and use the join function.

```
        <div className = {attachedClasses.join(' ')} >
            <Logo height="11%" />
            <nav>
                <NavigationItems />
            </nav>
        </div>    
    </Aux>
    )

}


export default sideDrawer;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use a function to return a string to your class for example:
`<div className = {attachedClasses.join(' ')} >` should be `<div className = {functionThatReturnsClassName()} >`.
The function should like something similar to this:

```
functionThatReturnsClassName = () => {
  if (something) {
   return attachedClasses[0]
   0 for the 'SideDrawer', 1 for the 'Open'
  }
  if(you want all of them condition) {
   return `${attachedClasses[0]} + ${attachedClasses[1]}`
  }
  return attacheClasses[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
className = "SideDrawer Open";
```

When you do this `className = {attachedClasses.join(' ')}` make sure that your `attachedClasses` is an array of string like `attachedClasses = ["SideDrawer", "Open"];.`

In your code attachedClasses is an HTML element, hence it won't work.

Suppose you have an array of classes:

```
arrayOfClasses = ['SideDrawer','Open','anyRandomClass'];
```

Now className prop takes a string as its value. To convert the array of classes to a single string, we make use of `join` operator.

```
className = {arrayOfClasses .join(' ')}
```

This will return a single string such as `"SideDrawer Open anyRandomClass"`

Comment: Can you please eloborate . I am still getting confused, I need to save these classes in an array variable and then assign that variable to a className along with join function.

Comment: Updated the answer. @SunnyGaonkar